# making an abstract callback method in php and passing arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: php

I had if/else foreach repeating in several methods, so I've decided to abstract it out, but got stuck because of convoluted logic.

[image]

`each_cpt` method looks like this:

```
private function each_cpt( $callback ) {

    //if ( isset( $cpts ) ) {
        //foreach ( $cpts as $cpt ) {
            //if ( $cpt['post_type'] == $post_type ) {
                return $callback( $cpt );
            //}
        //}
    //}

}
```

Problem is that sometimes I want to pass additional data from caller to callback. e.g.

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @since       1.0.0
 */
public function vehicle_post_type_link_id( $url, $post ) {

    $this->each_cpt( function( $cpt ){
        return home_url( $cpt['slug'] . '/' . $post->ID . '/' );
    } );

    return $url;

}
```

Notice I need `$post->ID` inside callback. But this is arbitrary, some other methods won't need `$post->ID`. So how do I make a proper abstract method that deals with my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP `use` syntax to bind a variable with the `closure`. The `use` keyword will make `$post` available to the function.

```
function ($cpt) use ($post) {
   return home_url(
       sprintf(
           "%s/%s/",
           $cpt['slug'],
           $post->ID
       )
   );
 }
```

Note that the `$this` is automatically binded to the closure starting from PHP 5.4. So if `$post` was a member variable of the class, it can be used using `$this` as `$this` is implicitly bounded to the `closure`.

Comment: awesome! and +1 for `$this` info